# Restore with back in time after fresh install of ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, backup, restore, backintime

I back up my `home`, which includes a list of installed softwares and PPA, on an external hard drive using back in time. I plan to do a fresh install of ubuntu. Will I then be able to install `back in time` on the fresh machine, then restore everything from there?

From what I have read on the internet, there are certain pitfalls, e.g. the two Ubuntu installs must be configured exactly the same, `back in time` settings must be the same, and I can only restore one folder at a time (!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** There are two more detailed articles on [BackInTime FAQ](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/wiki/FAQ) on how to [backup](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/wiki/FAQ#how-to-backup-debian-ubuntu-package-selection) and [restore](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/wiki/FAQ#how-to-restore-debian-ubuntu-package-selection) package selections.

Yes. This will work. Make sure you have included everything that is important to you in your last snapshot.
Run this commands to backup your PPA's and package selection:

```
mkdir ~/.apt-backup
sudo dpkg --get-selections > /home/<USER>/.apt-backup/package.list
sudo cp -aR /etc/apt/sources.list* /home/<USER>/.apt-backup/
sudo apt-key exportall > /home/<USER>/.apt-backup/Repo.keys
```

Just to make sure there are no corrupt files in snapshot you should run one last snapshot with `Use checksum to detect changes` enabled in Options on your old machine. (starting from 1.0.28 there is a command-line option `--checksum` for this, too. So you don't need to enable and than disable it again anymore).

Setup your new machine, install backintime again and copy `config` from your last snapshot folder `/path/to/backintime/HOST/USER/1/SNAPSHOT_ID` to `~/.config/backintime/`.

If Backintime doesn't find your old snapshots directly, go to `Settings` disable `Auto Host - User - Profile` and change Host and User entry so they match your old machine.
Now restore your home directory (and all other folders which are important to you).

Recreate your `/etc/apt/sources.list` if you had set something special in there. If your Ubuntu version changed don't just copy them from `~/.apt-backup/sources.list`

Restore apt-keys for your PPA's with `sudo apt-key add ~/.apt-backup/Repo.keys`

Make some "housecleaning" in `~/.apt-backup/package.list`. For example you don't want to install the old kernel again. So run `sed -e '/^linux-\(image\|headers\)/d' -i ~/.apt-backup/package.list`

Finally install all your old packages again with:

```
sudo apt-get update
cat ~/.apt-backup/package.list | sudo dpkg --set-selections
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Comment: Great answer! You should put this on Back-in-time FAQs somewhere since I think that most people need Back-in-time for disaster relief / fresh install case like this instead of the "Time machine"-like functionality.

Comment: That was my plan :) BTW I'm part of BIT dev team

Comment: I recognized your name :D Ubuntu has been failing me so I've been frequenting BIT launchpad a lot lately :(