# Transfer "BackinTime" saves from old PC to new one

Tags: backup, backintime

I'm changing my pc for a newer one. For two years, I have been keeping weekly "saves" using BackinTime. These saves are very helpful: they help to quickly go over the whole history of a project. Now, I'm wondering, is there a way to use these backintime saves from another PC than the one used to create them and, if yes, how (if it helps, currently these saves reside on an external HDD)?

Comment: Related Q&A that might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/378495/restore-with-back-in-time-after-fresh-install-of-ubuntu/380130#380130 (Note: not a duplicate because this question specifically asks about restoring BIT backups on a different machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one of the biggest advantage of BackInTime! You can access the snapshots from everywhere. Even without BackInTime because they are just normal files which you can browse with every file browser.

But you can also install BackInTime on your new PC and just copy over the config file `~/.config/backintime/config` or reconfigure everything in the same way like on your old machine.

You will have to uncheck `Auto Host/User/ProfileID` in `Settings > General` Tab and change `Host` and maybe `User` to match the name and user of your old PC. After that is done all your snapshots should show up in BackInTime again.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm member of BIT-Dev Team</sub>