# How to move entire Back In Time backup set to new hard drive?

Tags: backup, rsync, backintime

I have `backintime` storing backups to a hard drive. I'm replacing that hard drive and wish to copy everything from the old drive to the new one. How can I do that, preferably with `rsync`?

I have 600GB data in total and both drives are 2TB capacity, so space should not be an issue. My first attempt was to run `rsync -rt --progress /SOURCE /DESTINATION` but this filled the 2TB drive and failed. I thought soft/hard links might be the problem so I next tried `rsync -a --progress /SOURCE /DESTINATION` but this failed the same way.

There is a [similar question here](https://askubuntu.com/q/509857) about moving the metadata and settings to a new computer, but I'm trying to move my backup sets to a new drive within the same computer. The only change I want is the physical swap of the hard drives (and I'm okay editing`fstab`, etc, once I have a successful copy).

Is rsync the right way to do this, with some argument I've overlooked, or do I need to use something like `dd` to copy? I am reluctant to keep trying because each attempt takes many hours to run before failing.

Comment: I say use `dd bs=4M`

Comment: @AndroidDev How would specifying block size address the issue of 600GB 'filling' a 2TB drive?

Comment: Adding `bs=4M` will **drastically** speed it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `rsync -H` to preserve hard-links.

```
rsync -avhH --progress /SOURCE /DESTINATION
```

Alternative you could use `tar` to copy the snapshots because `tar` will preserve hard-links as well

```
cd /DESTINATION; tar cf - /SOURCE/* | tar xf -
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right it was the hard-links giving me trouble. This worked for me (and is more readable for when I forget what worked later...) `rsync -a --hard-links --progress /SOURCE /DESTINATION`.